# Keras: Text Preprocessing (Stopword Removal, etc.)

Tags: python, keras

I'm using Keras to do a multilabel classification task (Toxic Comment Text Classification on Kaggle).

I'm using the `Tokenizer` class to do some pre-processing like this:

```
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=10000)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(train_sentences)
train_sentences_tokenized = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(train_sentences)
max_len = 250
X_train = pad_sequences(train_sentences_tokenized, maxlen=max_len)
```

This is a good start, but I haven't removed stop words, stemmed words, etc.  For stop word removal, here's what I do before the above:

```
def filter_stop_words(train_sentences, stop_words):
    for i, sentence in enumerate(train_sentences):
        new_sent = [word for word in sentence.split() if word not in stop_words]
        train_sentences[i] = ' '.join(new_sent)
    return train_sentences

stop_words = set(stopwords.words("english"))
train_sentences = filter_stop_words(train_sentences, stop_words)
```

Shouldn't there be an easier way to do this within Keras?  Was hoping there was stemming capability as well, but docs don't indicate there is:

https://keras.io/preprocessing/text/

Any help on best practices for stop word removal and stemming would be awesome!

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

No, Keras is not a natural language processing library. You will have to handle any complex processing yourself. At this stage it might make sense to use an actual NLP library with a Python interface such as [NLTK](https://www.nltk.org/) or [Spacy](https://spacy.io/). `Tokenizer` is a small utility class for basic natural language tasks and you can extend it up to a certain point yourself but the NLP libraries will give much more including tokenisation, POS tagging and stemming.

Comment: spacy and nltk allow stop_words as a parameter.